# Integration Tests: Filling Autocomple Dropdown in Rails_Admin using Capybara for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, rails-admin

In my rails app, I'm using rails_admin. I want to fill a relationship. Say, a Post belongs to an Author. I want to set the author. rails_admin uses autocomplete form for selection of this data, i.e. xhr. How do I select value and submit this data using capybara. Normal select doesn't work here.

I'm assuming I need to take following actions

1. Click on carrot icon,
2. Select first value from dropdown

Or is there some other approach to fill such data, i.e execute script etc.
But how do I do that?

**Edit**:

As of now, I've started using selenium driver and I'm using following solution

```
within '#post_user_id_field' do
  find(".input-group-btn").click
end
page.execute_script(%q{$("ul#ui-id-3").find("li")[1].click()})
```

Suggest some better approach.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at [Using Capybara with RSpec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec) I found some helpful information. Without seeing any of your code, you can do something like the following (taking from the link above):

```
describe 'some stuff which requires js', :js => true do
  it 'will use the default js driver'
  it 'will switch to one specific driver', :driver => :webkit
end
```

This will enable javascript in your tests. If you are still having trouble with selection, you can do some debugging by placing `save_and_open_screenshot` in your test code to see what the javascript driver is seeing.

Answer (score 0):

How you do it really depends on the html on the page but basically it boils down to

```
find(:css, 'selector for the caret').click
find(:css, 'selector for the dropdown elements', text: 'text of the dropdown element to be selected').click
```

and make sure you're using a driver that supports JS - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers

Note: the :css in the find calls is not necessary if Capybara.default_selector == :css (which it does by default)